# set a image in browser cache

Tags: browser, browser-cache

Is there any way to set image in browser's cache? I am googing, but I couldn't find anything. If setting image at cache is possible, please give me the right direction.

Comment: Confused by your question, if someone is loading your website, they're going to save whatever images loaded by your website in their cache. Do you mean expiring cache?

Comment: that's a browser setting on client side only and as we all know cacheing works for and against us sometimes

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
img2=new Image();
img2.src="landscape3.gif";
function changeImage()
```

from http://www.w3schools.com/dhtml/tryit.asp?filename=trydhtml_image_preload

Comment: If I reload the website, again calls goes to both images. Right?

Comment: I think so - unless the persons browser is set to only get get new and updated files - but in my experience the cacheing of images and files is always unpredictable

Comment: eg setting in IE  http://www.google.co.za/imgres?imgurl=http://ahinea.com/pic/2005/ie-cache-setting-every-visit.png&imgrefurl=http://ahinea.com/en/tech/ie-dhtml-image-caching.html&h=350&w=354&sz=7&tbnid=h3xYiI8uIi9z9M:&tbnh=90&tbnw=91&zoom=1&usg=__xwzJPCUXfrowM7S_K7RoTMOK1-4=&docid=QuQM6BENwWSfZM&sa=X&ei=IqJrUfbHHpSyhAev4oCgDg&ved=0CD8Q9QEwAQ&dur=2534